# Calendar retorna objeto com 1 mês adicional

Tags: java

Tenho um aplicação Android que testa se as datas armazenadas em banco ultrapassaram o limite de tempo para realizar uma nova captura de dados através de uma determinada função. Consegui adicionar os valores do banco ao objeto do Calendar, porém o objeto é modificado sempre com 1 mês a mais do que o que foi realmente passado a ele.

```
Calendar dataBancoDor = Calendar.getInstance();

int diaDor = Integer.parseInt(dataDor.substring(0,2)); //29
int mesDor = Integer.parseInt(dataDor.substring(3,5)); //11
int anoDor = Integer.parseInt(dataDor.substring(6,10)); //2017


dataBancoDor.set(anoDor,mesDor,diaDor); // (2017,11,29)
String teste1 = String.valueOf(dataBancoDor.getTime());  // Fri Dec 29 2017
```

Onde está `Dec` deveria ser `Nov` (mês 11). O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os meses em java vão de 0 a 11. Por isso quando vc passa o mês 11 ele retorna dezembro, 0 = Janeiro, 1 = Fevereiro e assim por diante.

Comment: Muito obrigado!